# Postfix cannot receive mail

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have Ubuntu 10.04 on a VPS, installed and setup Postfix and Dovecot for a single system user following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot) guides. I can send e-mail, but cannot receive them.
I have a domain tema.ee, which has all necessary DNS records

```
tema@artemis:~$ host tema.ee
tema.ee has address 46.182.27.240
tema.ee mail is handled by 10 tema.ee.
tema@artemis:~$ host -t NS tema.ee
tema.ee name server ns2.selectel.org.
tema.ee name server ns1.selectel.org.
```

There is nothing in `/var/log/mail.log` at the time when I should receive e-mail besides imap login and disconnect messages.

Hosts file:

```
tema@artemis:~$ sudo cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1           localhost
46.182.27.240       tema.ee     artemis
```

Hostname:

```
tema@artemis:~$ hostname -f
tema.ee
```

Netstat output:

```
tema@artemis:~$ netstat -tap
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:imap2                 *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:36243                 *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:imaps                 *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:2025                  *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0     48 tema.ee:ssh             89-235-215-24.sat:62504 ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 tema.ee:imaps           89-235-215-24.sat:63988 ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 tema.ee:imaps           89-235-215-24.sat:63992 ESTABLISHED -                       
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2025               [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

This is my `main.cf` for postfix:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = tema.ee
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = tema.ee, localhost, artemis
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 # [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = 
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Actually, at first I thought that there was something to do with DNS, but I have setup a second virtual machine with a another domain (from a different registrar), made the same configuration and got the same result — I can send, but cannot receive mail. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a firewall issue.

Your host is unavailable on port 25

```
% nc 46.182.27.240 25
(UNKNOWN) [46.182.27.240] 25 (smtp) : No route to host
```

Look at (or show us) the output of

```
iptables-save
```

Comment: Thanks, appeared that I just changed port 25 to 2025 instead of adding a new line in master.cf

Comment: ok, glad to help.